# Turn .sql database dump into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a `.sql` file that contains a database dump. I would prefer to get this file into a pandas dataframe so that I can view the data and manipulate it. Willing to take any solution, but need explicit instructions, I've never worked with a .sql file previously.

The file's structure is as follows:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.11, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: somedatabase
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.11

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `selected`;
CREATE TABLE `selected` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `weekday` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monthday` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
... [more variables]) ENGINE=somengine DEFAULT CHARSET=something COLLATE=something;

LOCK TABLES `selected` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `selected` VALUES (dateval, weekdayval, monthdayval), (dateval, weekdayval, monthdayval), ... (dateval, weekdayval, monthdayval);
INSERT INTO `selected` VALUES (...), (...), ..., (...);
... (more insert statements) ...
-- Dump completed on timestamp
```

Comment: *I need to get this file into a pandas dataframe so that I can view the data and manipulate it* ... you can view and manipulate within a database. Consider importing file into MySQL or MariaDB (both free and compatible) and if needed import table/queries in pandas using `read_sql`.

Comment: Yes, I've considered this but haven’t found a way to connect to this database file from my local. Will gladly do this and then use pd.read_sql(), but need to know how.

Comment: 1) Install either of these databases which can run even on laptops; 2) Run your dump in the database; 3) Run SQL for viewing /manipulation or read into pandas. There are countless blogs/tutorials/books even SO posts on all three steps. Google/Bing is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sqlalchemy library for this:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html

Or alternatively you could use this:
https://pynative.com/python-mysql-database-connection/

The second option my be easier to load your data to mysql as you could just take your sql file text as the query object and pass it to the connection.

Something like this:

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='database',
                                             user='user',
                                             password='pw')
query = yourSQLfile    
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(query)
```

Once you've loaded your table you create the engine with sqlalchemy to connect pandas to your database and simply use the pandas read_sql() command to load your table to a dataframe object.

Another note is that if you just want to manipulate the data, you could take the values statement from the sql file and use that to populate a dataframe manually if you needed to. Just change the "Values (....),(....),(....)" to mydict = {[....],[....],[....]} and load it to a dataframe. Or you could dump the values statement to excel and delete the parentheses and do text to columns, give it headers and save it, then load it to a dataframe from excel. Or just manipulate it in excel (you could even use a concat formula to recreate the sql values syntax and replace the data in the sql file). It really depends on exactly what your end-goal here is.

Sorry you did not receive a timely answer here.